# Ajax with class js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
class newClass {
constructor(region) {
    this.region = region;
}
randomInteger() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (84 + 1)); //84 length
    return rand;
}
init() {
    let capital = this.region[this.randomInteger()].capitals.toLowerCase();
    let name = this.region[this.randomInteger()].name;
    let flag = this.region[this.randomInteger()].flag;
}

}


$.getJSON('regions.json', function (region) {

const output = '<p> ' + this.name +'</p>';
$('body').html(output);

 new newClass().init();
}
```

Есть класс в котором нужно инициализировать переменные, что есть. Доступ к этим переменным идет через json файл, но в таком случае выдает undefined, то есть не видит json. Как сделать так, чтобы он все таки выводил названия  из json и как перезаписать get запрос, чтобы он был в переменной и мы получали к нему доступ(то есть это маленькая часть кода и как бы не хотелось в get запрос тянуть весь код)?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class newClass {
  constructor(region) {
    this.region = region;
  }
  randomInteger() {
    let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.region.length);
    return rand;
  }
  init() {
    this.capital = this.region[this.randomInteger()].capitals.toLowerCase();
    this.name = this.region[this.randomInteger()].name;
    this.flag = this.region[this.randomInteger()].flag;
  }
}

$.getJSON('regions.json', function(region) {

  let nc = new newClass(region);
  nc.init();
  const output = '<p> ' + nc.name + '</p>';
  $('body').html(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```